# Wordpress - The Jetpack server could not communicate with your site’s XML-RPC URL

Tags: php, wordpress, jetpack

When I try to install Jetpack on my Wordpress website I get the following error:

> Error Details: The Jetpack server could not communicate with your
>   site’s XML-RPC URL. Please check to make sure example.com/xmlrpc.php
>   is working properly. It should show ‘XML‑RPC server accepts POST
>   requests only.’ on a line by itself when viewed in a browser and
>   should not have any blank lines or extra output anywhere.

When I goto the URL I see this:

```
XML‑RPC server accepts POST requests only.
```

Which is expected. It feels like I have tried everything I have googled and everything here:

https://jetpack.com/support/getting-started-with-jetpack/what-do-these-error-messages-mean/blank-lines-xmlrpc/

I have tried uninstalling all plugins and still does not work :(

What am I doing wrong?

Please help!

Comment: Switch the theme to a default one, like Twentyseventeen. After calling the xmlrpc.php on your site use "View source code" in order to make sure that definitely no other (invisible) output is generated in the response.

Comment: Did you try to deactivate all plugins and reactivate step by step to find out which one is causing the issue? If the fault is  still showing up without any active plugins, probably it's a template-issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the link, they specifically mention whitespace or output that could be causing issues, and ask you to check there isn't any before the opening PHP tags etc.

The reason they talk about this is because if there has been any output at all, then PHP will no longer be able to send any HTTP headers!

If your files look ok, then I guess (guarantee even?) that your `display_errors` is turned on. Depending on the level of `error_reporting` in your ini file, any little notice or warning will create output, and therefore stop any further HTTP headers from being set.

For the best error logging experience (and hopefully to also fix your error), set `error_reporting` to `-1`, turn `display_errors off`, and set a custom `error_log`. Then in the terminal, type `tail -f /path/to/error_log`. Your notices, warnings and errors will now scroll past in real time, without distorting your web page's display.